# Access Array in different Swift file

Tags: swift

I have an Array called results that I created in a file I have called ParseJSON.swift that is called from ViewController.swift, but when I want to access the array in a separate file called MyView.swift, it says "Use of unresolved identifier 'results'"

Obviously the issue is that MyView.swift does not have access to the elements in ParseJSON.swift, but I was wondering what the typical solution is for this?

In ParseJSON.swift:

```
var results = [Int]()
```

In MyView.swift:

```
var rect = DataRectangle<Int>()
rect.data = results << error here
```

Comment: It's a straightforward question...the code isn't necessary but I will update it.

Comment: can results be access from ViewController.swift?

Comment: Yes @anishparajuli because I call parseJSON(fileName) from it.

Comment: can you show your DataRectange class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do not know what your code structure is, but in general if you want to access some variables of one file to another:

Here is the way in which you can do that:

```
//First file
    class ParseJson: NSObject {

        var results: NSArray = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]

    }

//controller    
    class MyView: UIViewController {

       var copiedArray: NSArray = NSArray()

       override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

             var json: ParseJson = ParseJson() //Create object of ParseJson
             copiedArray = json.results        //access class variables
        }}
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a Separate file called Manager.swift and place this code in it...

```
//manager.swift

import Foundation

struct Manager {

static var results = [Int]()


}
```

Clean your project by pressing Shift+Command+K.

Now you can access and change that variable from any view controller. Here is an example.

```
//viewController.swift
    println(Manager.results)
```